# Spring Boot jar into existing Spring Project

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, logging

We have an existing Spring MVC based application. I was asked to plug-in a customization/utility to this project. I am not supposed to do any changes to the existing application. 
For the new utility, I thought of doing it through a Spring boot jar. I created a Spring boot jar and placed in the lib folder of the existing application. However, I am facing few issues with this approach and wanted to know if this is the correct  approach and if there are any suggestions out there. The issues are:

1. The logging level of the Spring boot affects the logging level of the existing application. How can I avoid that?
2. The Spring MVC application and the Spring boot jar both are based on different versions of Spring. What if there are some common class files or packages in both Spring MVC application and the Spring boot jar but with different versions? Will this create any conflicts or will it affect the functionality? I don't want my Spring boot jar to affect the functionality/logging of the existing application. I just want the Spring boot jar to work whenever it is being called explicitly.

For logging issue, I have tried to use something like below in `application.properties` file but the issue with that is that those settings are considered only if you run the application through @SpringBootApplication main class. But if you just want to package your functionality in a jar file then the `application.properties` file is not considered.

```
logging.level.org.springframework = OFF
```